# Cannot GET / while using a grammar Api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am trying to use API to check the grammar of the sentence. but when I don't know it is giving me the error `Cannot GET /` please tell me where I am wrong.

```
    const express = require('express');
    const https = require('https');

const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
     

    const text = req.body.cityName;
    const url  = "https://www.stands4.com/services/v2/grammar.php?uid=8816&tokenid=u9K3iEcIcjmS84B6&text=" + text + "&format=json";
    https.get(url,function(response){

            response.on("data", function(data){
                const grammar = JSON.parse(data);
                const fault = grammar.matches.message;
                console.log(fault);
                res.write("<p>The problem in text :" + fault + "</p>");
                res.send();
            });
    });


});


app.listen(port = 3000, function(){

    console.log("Server is running on port 3000 ");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access localhost:3000 via the browser? if so you're using `app.post` change it to `app.get`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hit your own API, then the problem is that your controller is being a POST controller. That is why it throws you `Cannot GET`.

You can change `app.post` to `app.get` or, you can try calling POST method instead of GET.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when target an invalid endpoint, make sure that you use correct url and correct method

Answer (score 0):

Your controller is a POST controller thus the error. You either do a post call or you change to the controller to GET.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) ...
```